# xcode 6: font size changing when scrolling dynamic tables out of range

Tags: swift, uitableview, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest, uifont

The font size for textViews in viewControllers which use dynamic tables changes when the row scrolls out of view. This does not happen with static tables. The font size is set correctly in the storyboard.

Do I have to explicitly change the font size in the custom classes?

Here is some code (as requested by @neo):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CREWBasicSuppliesCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellName) as! CREWBasicSuppliesCell
    //        NSLog("section %d", indexPath.section)
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        var row = 0
        row = indexPath.row
        var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Switch")
        var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(viewName = %@)",viewName)
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        // Execute the fetch request
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if var fetchResults = managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [Switch] {
            var recordCount = 0
            recordCount = fetchResults.count
            if recordCount > 0 {
                var appConfig  = fetchResults [row]
                cell.mySwitch.on = appConfig.switchValue.boolValue
                cell.myTextView.text = appConfig.switchDescription
            }
        }
     } else { // section 0
        cell.mySwitch.hidden = true
        var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "View")
        var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(viewName = %@)",viewName)
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        // Execute the fetch request
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if var fetchResults = managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [View] {
            var row = 0
            row = indexPath.row
            var recordCount = 0
            recordCount = fetchResults.count
            if recordCount > 0 {
                var appConfigView  = fetchResults [row]
                cell.myTextView.text = appConfigView.viewDescription
            }
        }
    }
    //        NSLog("section %d", indexPath.section)
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another post indicated that the problem was solved by making the UITextView selectable. This worked for me.